# The difference between "come at a cost of/to"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is there any differences between "come at a cost of" and "come at a cost to"?

Like

> Energy efficiency may **come at the cost of** consumer confidence
>
> Free drug samples **come at a cost to** patients.
>
> Insects also readily evolve resistance to chemical insecticides, and increased use of these chemicals would **come at a great cost to** human health.

Comment: my vote is for *at the cost **of*** That's an idiom and we all know that. I'm confused as I found examples using *cost to* as well! Nice question. +1

Comment: I think "a cost of X" means we spend X, whereas in "a cost to Y", Y is who or what that is affected by the spending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think that *at a cost of* describes *what it will cost*, e.g. *at the cost of a lot of money*. Or, in the example, it will cost consumer confidence (that is, there will be less consumer confidence because of energy efficiency).

*At a cost to* indicates *who* is paying the price, in the example, the patients pay the price.

So, yes, there is a difference. If I would write your second example as follows:

> Free drug samples come at a cost **of** patients.

This would imply that the free drug samples cost us patients, presumably because they die!

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle distinction here that is easily overlooked, and appears to have gotten mixed in with the original question: "at **a** cost of" is not the same as "at **the** cost of".

"At **a** cost **of** (something)" says that (something) is a measurement of *how much* it will cost:

> Changing the health care system will come at a cost of several million dollars.

However, "at **the** cost **of** (something)" usually means that (something) *will happen* as a result:

> Changing the health care system may come at the cost of reduced care for some patients.

On the other hand, "at **a** cost **to** (something)" means that (something) *will be harmed* in the process:

> Changing the health care system may come at a cost to patients.